# Вывод дерева на PHP

Tags: массивы, рекурсия, php

есть древовидный массив вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [address] => root addr           
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                            [address] => child addr                  
                            [parent_id] => 12
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 16
                                            [address] => child addr 2
                                            [parent_id] => 11
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 19
                                                            [address] => child addr 3 
                                                            [parent_id] => 16
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 18
                                            [address] => child addr 4
                                            [parent_id] => 11
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 20
                                            [address] => child addr 5
                                            [parent_id] => 11
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [address] => root addr 2        
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

)
```

есть функция для его вывода:

```
function printTree($data, $level = 0, $p_counter = 1) {

            foreach ($data as $item) {

                if ($item['parent_id'] == 0) {
                    $addr =  $p_counter . '. ' . $item['address'];
                    $p_counter++;
                }

                else if ($item['parent_id'] != 0) {

                    $addr =  str_repeat(' - ', $level) . $item['address'];

                } else {
                     $addr = $item['address'];              
                }

                global $result;

                $result['aaData'][] = Array(
                 $addr,

             );

                if (isset($item['children'])) {                    
                    printTree($item['children'], $level + 1, $p_counter + 1);
                }

            }

            return $result;        
        }
```

результат ее выполнения:

```
1. root addr  
- child addr        
- - child arr 2 
- - - child arr 3        
- - child addr 4     
- - child addr 5     
2. root addr 2
```

Нужно получить такой вид:

```
1. root addr  
1-1. child addr        
1-1-1. child arr 2 
1-1-1-1. child arr 3        
1-1-2. child addr 4     
1-1-3. child addr 5     
2. root addr 2
```

как организовать нумерацию у child элементов?

Answer (score 1):

```
function printTree($data, $level = 0, $p_counter = 1, $prefix="") { 
    $i=0;           
    foreach ($data as $item) {

        if ($item['parent_id'] == 0) {
            $addr = /* $p_counter . '. ' .*/ $item['address'];
            $p_counter++;
        }

        else if ($item['parent_id'] != 0) {
            $addr =  $item['address'];
        } else {
             $addr = $item['address'];              
        }

        echo $prefix.(++$i)." ". $addr."\n";

        global $result;

        $result['aaData'][] = Array($addr,);

        if (isset($item['children'])) {                    
            printTree($item['children'], $level + 1, $p_counter + 1, $prefix.($i).".");
        }
    }
    return $result;        
}

printTree($a,0,1,"");
```

результат

```
1 root addr
1.1 child addr 
1.1.1 child addr 2
1.1.1.1 child addr 3 
1.1.2 child addr 4
1.1.3  child addr 5
2 root addr 2
```

Код специально не чистил, просто ваше допили до нужного вывода. Да и заодно подправляя под себя, еще раз по нему пробежитесь, лишним не будет )))